# Mudar o tipo de coluna em Dados no R Studio

Tags: r

Gostaria de saber onde consigo um material sobre modelagem de dados no R Studio... preciso modificar algumas colunas, alterando de texto para valor, por exemplo, mas não sei qual comando utilizar.

Alguém poderia me indicar algum material? ou site de apoio?

Comment: Vê se esses links te ajudam: [Minicurso de Estatística Básica: Introdução ao software R](http://www.uft.edu.br/engambiental/prof/catalunha/arquivos/r/r_bruno.pdf) (Esse é o que mais me ajuda) [O software R como instrumento de ensino em Estatística Básica](http://www.im.ufrj.br/probest/Minicurso_R_SBPO_2010.pdf) [Tópicos de Estatística utilizando R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Itano-descriptive-stats.pdf) [Leitura e manipulação de Dados](http://ecologia.ib.usp.br/bie5782/doku.php?id=bie5782:03_apostila:04-dados)

Comment: `"alterando de texto para valor"`: tente `as.numeric(as.character(x))`, onde `x` é o vector a alterar.

Comment: geralmente isso reflete problemas na leitura dos dados... O R usa "." como separador de decimais enquanto é comum existir bases em que os decimais são separados por ",". tente ler com read.csv2

Comment: Obrigado @RuiBarradas... vou testar...

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a resposta... basta inserir o procedimento de **colnames**..

***colnames(dataset)[nº correspondente da coluna no dataset] <- "Novo nome da coluna"***

Assim consigo mudar o nome da coluna, desde que eu saiba qual a posição da mesma..